# Zip Exception not getting caught correctly

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, zip, unzip

Here in this piece of code I am trying to catch zipping exception.

```
try {
    // Your code that may throw exceptions
} catch (ZipException e) {
    // Handle ZipException
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle IOException
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle other exceptions
}
```

I have categorised my exception in above format. Now I am getting "Invalid zip file format" which should ideally be caught in ZipException or IOException but it is getting caught in generic Exception.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Is this C++? The language needs to be a tag. What Zip library are you using?

Comment: What is the exact exception type (from the stacktrace)?